# SharePoint Yes/No fields not updating from Power Automate

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, power-automate

I have a simple Flow to create an item when a new email arrives:

[When a new email arrives > Parse JSON > Create item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fu3ma.png)

The flow does work however, none of the Yes/No fields are not updating to Yes when the incoming value is true; the default value is No so false values are working as expected.

***When a new email arrives***

```
{ ... "Driver": true, ... }
```

***Parse JSON***

```
{
    ...
    "Driver": true,
    ...
}
```

***Create item***

INPUTS

```
...
Driver
 true
...
```

OUTPUTS

```
...
Driver
 true
...
```

***List Item in SharePoint***

[Driver (Yes/No) is un-checked/false](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3wyX.png)

I have read the solution to Flow fails on Yes/No column (Big Flow) but to no avail.

https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Using-Flows/Flow-fails-on-Yes-No-column-Big-Flow/m-p/35116#M1086

To confirm, I have *unsuccessfully* tried to add the following dynamic content options:

```
// In-correctly assumed the below line should work since a Yes/No field is a simple Boolean field;
// returns true but doesn't check the Driver checkbox in Item
body('Parse_JSON')?['json']?['Driver']

// Solution to Flow fails on Yes/No column (Big Flow);
// https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Using-Flows/Flow-fails-on-Yes-No-column-Big-Flow/m-p/35116#M1086
// returns true but doesn't check the Driver checkbox in Item
equals(body('Parse_JSON')?['json']?['Driver'], true)

// All returns true but doesn't check the Driver checkbox in Item
if(body('Parse_JSON')?['json']?['Driver'], true, false)
if(body('Parse_JSON')?['json']?['Driver'], 'True', 'False')
if(equals(body('Parse_JSON')?['json']?['Driver'], true), true, false)
if(equals(body('Parse_JSON')?['json']?['Driver'], true), 'True', 'False')

// Throws error; and Flow fails as expected
if(body('Parse_JSON')?['json']?['Driver'], 'Yes', 'No')
if(equals(body('Parse_JSON')?['json']?['Driver'], true), 'Yes', 'No')
```

Now, I am just guessing so what am I missing?!

To summarise, my question is how do I successfully update Yes/No fields when creating an item from a MS Flow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stumbled onto a work-around, and accepted solution, where using the Send an HTTP request to SharePoint action to update the Description (Display Text) & URL fields of a Hyperlink field.

I found this post most helpful: [Updating a Hyperlink field (both url and description) using Flow?](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/PowerApps-Flow/Updating-a-Hyperlink-field-both-url-and-description-using-Flow/m-p/239331/highlight/true#M1477)

I used the same approach to update all Yes/No fields to Yes when the incoming value is true. Here are the key settings others may find useful.

```
Site Address: https://MyFakeSite.sharepoint.com/
Method: POST
Url: _api/web/lists/GetByTitle('MyFakeList')/Items(@{body('Create_item')?['ID']})
Headers: {
  "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
  "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
  "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE",
  "IF-MATCH": "*"
}
Body: {
    '__metadata': {
      'type': 'SP.Data.MyFakeListItem'
    },
    'Driver': @{toLower(string(equals(body('Parse_JSON')?['json']?['Driver'], true)))},
    ...
}
```